# A problem about probability theory and set theory

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I'm studying the fact that if $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $\{Y_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that $Y_{i}\sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(\lambda)$ defined in the space $(X, E, P)$, then $X$ is necessarily uncountable.

**Approach:** Suppose by way of contradiction that  $X$ is a countable set. Then we have $X=\{ x_{n} | n\in \mathbb{N},~x_{n} \in \{0,1\} \}$. Then $\displaystyle X= \bigcap_{n\geq 1} (Y_{n}=x_{n}) \subset T_{k}= \bigcap_{1\leq n \leq k} (Y_{n}=x_{n})$ for all integer $k\geq 1$. Now maybe I need to look at suitable $k$? But how can I continue from here?

---

Maybe a way to complete the proof, in $X$ either the number of ones or zeros is infinite, assume Wlog the we have infinitely many ones?

Comment: Just the existence of iid $Y_i$ on that space implies that $(X,E,P)$ is uncountable? That is quite interesting. +1

Comment: Since the $Y_i$ are independent, there has to be a sample for all possible values of all $Y_i$.  That is, $(Y_1, Y_2, \ldots)$ is a surjection onto $\{0,1\}^\omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_0 \in X$ be fixed but arbitrary, and define $y_n := Y_n(x_0) \in \{ 0,1 \}$ for $n \in \Bbb{N}$.
For brevity, let $\alpha := \max \{ \lambda, 1 - \lambda \}$.
Note for each $N \in \Bbb{N}$ that $M_N := \bigcap_{n=1}^N \{ x \in X \colon Y_n(x) = y_n \}$
satisfies $\{ x_0 \} \subset M_N$.
By the independence of the $Y_n$, we have
$$
  0
  \leq P(\{ x_0 \})
  \leq P(M_N)
  = \prod_{n=1}^N
      P(Y_n = y_n)
  \leq \prod_{n=1}^N \alpha
  = \alpha^N
  \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} 0 .
$$
We have thus shown $P(\{ x_0 \}) = 0$ for all $x_0 \in X$.

Thus, $X$ cannot be countable since otherwise $1 = P(X) = \sum_{x \in X} P(\{ x \}) = 0$.

Comment: This's a nice solution. Thank you so much :-)